# How to set up two domains to point at the same app with Passenger but with different Rails functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have two domains on Apache: `domain1.tld` & `domain2.tld`

Presently I have `domain1.tld` working perfectly with Passenger, but I also need `domain2.tld` to point to this same application, but when it reaches this second domain, it will have different functionality (ie, call a different controller and have some different routes) than when a user hits `domain1.tld`.

How do you configure this traditionally in Rails?

As far as the Apache config goes, I have the following for `domain1.tld`:

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/apps/domain1.tld/production/current/public
<Directory /home/username/apps/domain1.tld/production/current/public>
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
   Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/username/logs/domain1.tld.error.log
CustomLog /home/username/logs/domain1.tld.access.log combined
```

What would be needed for `domain2.tld` for the Apache config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup at some point might also evolve into having two completely separate apps. And I'll let you be the better judge of when and when not that might be required. Having said that you can achieve what you asked using Routing Constraints in Rails. For ex: (Please note that this is not the only way of achieving this, but my preferred way)

```
root to: 'home#index1', as: :domain1, constraints: {|req| req.host == 'domain1.tld' }
root to: 'home#index2', as: :domain2, constraints: {|req| req.host == 'domain2.tld'}
root to: 'home#index'
```

To add a new Apache host, one adds another virtual host and points to the same public folder as the main application.  So in this case, it would be a matter of creating all of the same information as in the first config file, but just adding the `domain2.tld` as the new virtual host's name.

Comment: Appreciate that answer.  Since you may have missed the part regarding `httpd` config, I've clarified my question above with some more specifics on my current config and a direct callout to the other part of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can achieve this on Apache level. Since, the responsibility of calling the appropriate controller action belongs in the Rails stack not in Apache.

Comment: Well it is a two fold issue.  You are correct about your suggestion on the rails configuration, but Apache likewise has to grok `domain2.tld`.

Comment: Do you have both Apache and the Rails app on the same server or different servers?

Comment: In this case Apache with Passenger and the Rails apps are on the same server.

Comment: Ok, you might want to look at Apache Virtual Hosts capability then.. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: So I got the solution figured out for Apache 2.4 and talking to cPanel technical support.  In my case it was a matter of creating a new folder under the template config hierarchy `/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/${usrname}/${hstnm}/rails.conf` so that the `domain2.tld` was essentially the same as `domain1.tld` but simply under that new folder which would create the proper hostname directive in httpd's config.